# How to force Javamail to clear its message cache?

Tags: java, optimization, memory, jakarta-mail

I'm running a server that uses Javamail. It has a count listener with IMAP's IDLE, such that when a new mail comes in, certain piece of code is executed. The list of new message is given to my listener as a parameter. I read the information off it and be done with it. All is good except my server leaks a lot of memory!! I did a heap dump and found that the class [Lcom.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage is using a lot of memory. It seems an array of IMAPMessage is referenced by the object com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.

Is there some caching going on? I don't need to access those messages ever again except for the first time it comes in. How do I force the cache to clear? How can I stop javamail from leaking?

Answer (score 1):

I found this reference in the Javamail Forum
[How to force Javamail to clear its message cache?](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1587567)

And then did a bit of digging.  While I haven't found a way to remove or shrink the "cache", I have found that the biggest portion of that cache are the message's headers.  There are two copies of the headers inside IMAPMessage, one that it has and one inside MIMEMessage that it populates.  Now the trouble comes in when you want to clear out this information as they only give you access to clearing the information in IMAPMessage.  The headers in MIMEMessage cannot be cleared.  Further, they cannot be removed. Here is the code from InternetHeaders.remove(String)

```
/**
 * Remove all header entries that match the given name
 * @param   name    header name
 */
public void removeHeader(String name) { 
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    InternetHeader h = (InternetHeader)headers.get(i);
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(h.getName())) {
    h.line = null;
    //headers.remove(i);
    //i--;    // have to look at i again
    }
}
}
```

Regardless, I was able to decrease the memory stored by the MessageCache dramatically by going in and nulling out all of these values.

```
Field headerField = MimeMessage.class.getDeclaredField("headers");
headerField.setAccessible(true);
InternetHeaders headers = (InternetHeaders) headerField.get(imapMessage);
if (headers != null) {
   Enumeration<?> allHeaders = headers.getAllHeaders();
   ArrayList<String> headerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (allHeaders.hasMoreElements()) {
       Header header = (Header) allHeaders.nextElement();
       headerNames.add(header.getName());
   }
   for (String headerName : headerNames) {
       headers.setHeader(headerName, null);
   }
}
```

Not the prettiest, but it decreases my memory footprint of one folder from 40MB to 20MB.  I'm going to see if there are other ways to do this.  Ideally, I think that I'd create my own overridden IMAPMessage class, but that seems very difficult to plumb in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another Java Mail implementation if you don't like Sun's. GNU Classpath have one (at http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/javamail.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html), you pas a boolean to indicate that deleted messages should be expunged:

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
folder.close(aBoolean);
store.close();
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to clearing/emptying the Javamail cache.